# Redirect cloudfront requests to new URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a URL, that is backed by cloudfront to host images. I've since then moved to a new image hosting solution, and need to redirect traffic from the old URL to the new URL, efficiently and without degrading user experience.

For example:

When my website loads an image from www.images.companyName.com/bucket/itemGroup1/itemId, I need traffic to go instead to www.someWebsite.com/xx/bucket/itemGroup1/itemId (notice the path has also slightly changed)

How can this be done leveraging AWS, if it cannot, what other options do I have. I've been thinking Lambda@Edge, but I am not sure if this is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time Migration where you are expecting to achieve zero down time for the end users, you can set up a syncing mechanism from old bucket to new (keeping the old files also for the moment) and update the Cloudfront distribution with both Origins and Behaviors as necessary. This is assuming some clients will have the old paths and some will access the latest. Then later analyzing the Cloudfront logs you can decide to remove old Origin and Behaviors.

If you are planning for an URL rewrite, then you need to use Lambda@Edge for this, specially if there is no way of informing the end users that the URL is updated.